# Understanding Ruby logical operators

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

I'm new to Ruby and thought that it would be a great way to learn more by solving the problems at Project Euler.

Here's what I came up with using brute force for Problem 5:

```
#What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?
end_point = 1_000_000_000 
start_point = 2_520
(start_point..end_point).each do |number|
  flag = true
  (2..20).each do |divisor|
    flag = flag & ( number % divisor ) == 0 ? true : false
    end
  print number.to_s + "\n" if flag
end
```

This runs for a long time and gives no answer.

Then I used the same logic to write a C++ program to do the same task:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned long int solution = 2520;
  while(1)
  {
    bool flag = true;
    for(int divisor=2;divisor<=20;divisor++)
    {
      if( solution % divisor == 0)
        flag = flag & true;
      else{
        flag = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(flag == true){
      cout<<solution<<endl;
      break;
    }
    solution++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This one gives me the correct solution and runs for barely a second. The execution time doesn't really concern me as Ruby is interpreted and C++ compiled but Ruby's failure at returning the correct answer does surprise me. I think it might be because of me trying to write C++ Ruby style and not the actual Ruby way.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: I have not run either of the proposed solutions below to completion - they still take a long time - so correctness is not guaranteed!**

The line where you update `flag` is the problem. You're using `&` (bitwise-and) rather than `&&` (Boolean-and).

Among other problems, `&` has higher operator precedence than `==`, so your line is interpreted as (since `? true : false` is redundant):

```
flag = (flag & (number % divisor)) == 0
```

Now, it appears that `true & some_integer` is `true`, which is not `== 0`, so `flag` is always set to `false`.

Instead, you want:

```
flag = flag && (number % divisor == 0)
```

or, more succinctly and Rubyish:

```
flag &&= number % divisor == 0
```

An alternative solution would be to do:

```
i = 1
while true
  break unless (2..20).any? {|d| i % d != 0}
  i+=1
end
puts i
```

Comment: Your alternate solution is just what i was looking for,
Isn't it wonderful how people can write code that is so much more beautiful than I can in ruby. I wonder how i can really learn this ruby way.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between && and 'and'. Initially I used 'and' since that didn't work I tried &.

Comment: You're welcome. I think the relevant mindset here is that Ruby likes doing things directly with collections; that is, it's more Rubyish to call an implicitly-looping method on an Enumerable than it is to explicitly loop over the contents. By the way, both methods give the right answer, but mine is quicker (because `any?` short-circuits as soon as it fails).

Comment: @nikhil - have a look at [this excellent blog post](http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) on the difference between `&&`, `||` and `and`, `or`. (And I think I need to start using `and` and `or` more!)

Answer (score 3):

I actually solved this problem without writing a program for it.
This is the logic I used :

Write down all prime numbers less than 20 (target).

`[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]`

For each prime number, raise it to the maximum power for which it is lesser than the target (20).

`2**4 * 3**2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19`

For doing it programmatically use the Sieve of Eratosthenes - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes algorithm for iterating over the prime numbers. For each prime number in the list, find the maximum power to which it is raised to get a number lesser than the target (20). You can find the power using this formula : `(Math.log(target)/Math.log(i)).floor`

Assuming you get the array of primes : `nums = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]`

Then you can get the answer easily by using this :

```
nums.map {|i| i**((Math.log(target)/Math.log(i)).floor)}.inject(:*)
```